# How to call self executing function from another file

Tags: javascript

I'm studying the object oriented features of Javascript and I'm looking at the "Module Pattern". I have a self executing function, which I'd like to call from another file but I keep getting errors.

Here's the self executing module:

```
var basketModule = (function () {
    var basket = [];
    function doSomethingPrivate() {
      //...
    }
    // Return an object exposed to the public
    return {
      // Add items to our basket
      addItem: function( values ) {
          basket.push(values);
      },
      // Get the count of items in the basket
      getItemCount: function () {
          return basket.length;
      }, 
   };
})();
```

I'm trying to use this from another file called `Run.js`:

```
var basketModule = require("./basketModule");

basketModule.addItem({
  item: "bread",
  price: 0.5
});
console.log( basketModule.getItemCount() );
```

When I run this `node Run.js` I get an error:

> basketModule.addItem is not a function.

I tried adding a call to basketModule like this: `basketModule();` immediately after the require but this results in

> TypeError: basketModule is not a function.

What am I missing?

```
console.log( basketModule.getItemCount());
```

Comment: You need to export your code: `module.exports = basketModule`. Look at the https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_module_exports

Comment: In your code, `basketModule` can't be defined by an anonymous function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to module export the class before you can use it by calling require, add `module.exports = basketModule;` after the function.

```
var basketModule = (function () {

var basket = [];
function doSomethingPrivate() {
  //...
}

// Return an object exposed to the public
return {

  // Add items to our basket
  addItem: function( values ) {
      basket.push(values);
  },

  // Get the count of items in the basket
  getItemCount: function () {
      return basket.length;
  }, 


};
 })();


 module.exports = basketModule;
```

Also in your other file

```
var basketModule = require("./src/basketModule.js");

basketModule.addItem({
    item: "bread",
    price: 0.5
});

console.log(basketModule.getItemCount());
```

In the above I have created a new instance of our basketModule and then called `.addItem()`on it.

Comment: Adding `module.exports = basketModule` got rid of the errors, but trying to use `new basketModule` results in `basketModule is not a function`.  You answered my question so I'll accept the answer but I'd love to know why the new error is happening.

Comment: You may also need to include `.js` at the end of you're require only just noticed. Going to quickly reinvent your example and test!

Comment: @Eddy I totally second guessed myself with an edit here in my answer I'll update it, works on testing though.

Comment: So you're able to use `new` and create another object, in your testing? I wonder if you need a constructor for that.

Comment: In your case because it's a self executing anonymous function you'll only be able to have one instance of the object by calling `var basketModule = require("./src/basketModule.js")` If you did want more the new keyword isn't available here as a constructor will not be available. The use of the new keyword was what I second guessed myself on here because I originally didn't have it in place as I presumed you couldn't do it. Turns out I was correct the first time around.

Comment: You'll notice how strikingly similar your function is to the famous singleton pattern here for example http://www.dofactory.com/javascript/singleton-design-pattern

Comment: Right. Thank you.